# sed with a regex starting with space and containing dash

Tags: regex, sed

In bash I want to parse filenames of mp3 files where the separator between track number, artist and title is " - " (space dash space). The expected result is as follows:
`Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)`

My sed command as follows:

`echo "03 - Artist name first-middle name - Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)" | sed -E 's/^([^ - ]*[ - ]){2}//'`

The result: `Artist name first-middle name - Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)`

I'm stuck here and can't make " - " as one term. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your hints!

Here sample data:

```
'01 - Skyway - Chillwave - Synthwave - Retrowave Mix.mp3'
'02 - Baldocaster - Astral Dive.mp3'
'05 - Jacket. and Shadowrunner - Deathtouch.mp3'
'06 - Night Drive - A Synthwave Mix.mp3'
'07 - Shadowrunner and Syst3m-Glitch - Eastbound Plane Mattaei (Original - Long Mix).mp3'
```

In the bash scriptI want to set the title variable as follows:

`` title=`echo ${filename} | sed -E "s/^([^${SEPARATOR}]*[${SEPARATOR}]){4}//" ``

where SEPARATOR is a variable as well containing e.g. " - "

Comment: Your code actually works with 7: `$ echo "03 - Artist name first-middle name - Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)" | sed -E 's/^([^ - ]*[ - ]){7}//'
Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)`

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. Unfortunately that only works for this particular filename but not for others. Any idea how to write the regex so it is taken as a work and not single characters? Additionally, in the end I'd like to set a parameter and not just a string.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using parameter expensions.

```bash
$ filename="03 - Artist name first-middle name - Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)"
$ filename="${filename#* - * - }"
$ echo "$filename"
Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)
```

Comment: Use `"{filename% - * - *}"` if you want to remove characters from behind.

Comment: Thanks @Darkman! So far this is the only solution that can be used using a constant as the separator. Could you please elaborate a little how that works?

Comment: @eyesound `expansions` not `expensions`. [Here a link from GNU website explains about it in great details.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this with basic sed is

```
sed -e 's/ - \(.*\)/;;\1/' -e 's/ - \(.*\)/;;\1/' -e 's/.*;;//'
```

which is three commands:

1. turn the first delimiter (between track number and artist) into ;;
2. turn the second delimiter (between artist and track) into ;;
3. delete everything before and including the last ;;

The reason it's tricky is that basic sed's matchers are inherently greedy, so `.*` always eats as many characters as possible. You can work around that by eating from the end of the line instead of the beginning.

If you want your separator to be a configurable pattern:

```
$ SEPARATOR=' - '
$ sed -e 's/'"$SEPARATOR"'\(.*\)/;;\1/' -e 's/'"$SEPARATOR"'\(.*\)/;;\1/' -e 's/.*;;//' data
Chillwave - Synthwave - Retrowave Mix.mp3
Astral Dive.mp3
Deathtouch.mp3
A Synthwave Mix.mp3
Eastbound Plane Mattaei (Original - Long Mix).mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ title=$(sed -E 's/.*- ([[:alpha:] ]+(\([^)]*\))?\..*)/\1/' input_file)
$ echo "$title"
Retrowave Mix.mp3'
Astral Dive.mp3'
Deathtouch.mp3'
A Synthwave Mix.mp3'
Eastbound Plane Mattaei (Original - Long Mix).mp3'
```

Comment: That works for exactly the example but not for artist names without dash.

Comment: @eyesound Can you add sample data that truly represents the data you have? If the match will always contain a single dash, you could also try `sed -E 's/.*- ([^-]*-.*)/\1/' file`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added additional sample data and the integrated code snippet.

Comment: @eyesound I have edited my solution according to the new data. Please also consider adding the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and a capture group:

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]+ - (.+)/\1/' file
```

Output

```
Artist name first-middle name - Title of the Track (Original Version - Long Edit)
Skyway - Chillwave - Synthwave - Retrowave Mix.mp3
Baldocaster - Astral Dive.mp3
Jacket. and Shadowrunner - Deathtouch.mp3
Night Drive - A Synthwave Mix.mp3
Shadowrunner and Syst3m-Glitch - Eastbound Plane Mattaei (Original - Long Mix).mp3
```

If you want to match the pattern with the parenthesis and the `.mp3` extension only:

```
sed -En 's/^[0-9]+ - (.*\([^()]+\))\.mp3$/\1/p' file
```

Output

```
Shadowrunner and Syst3m-Glitch - Eastbound Plane Mattaei (Original - Long Mix)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` using a `space dash space` as a separator.

```
awk -F' - ' -v OFS=' - ' '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))}'
```